# Comparar dos string sin usar el método .front() en C++

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Estoy intentando comparar solamente el primer valor de dos cadenas y en todos los foros que investigo utilizan el método `.front()` y hasta donde tengo entendido ese método solo está disponible a partir de la versión 11 de C++, entonces: ¿Qué alternativas existen a este método?

---

Aquí hay un código de ejemplo que no funciona junto con el error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

string aux[1];

int main(){

aux[0] = "camisa";

if (aux[0].front() == "c"){
    cout << "correcto";
    }
}
```

El error que me muestra es:

> [Error] 'std::string' has no member named 'front'

Comment: Hay tantas formas que da miedo: `*begin( ) == 'x'`, `*c_str( ) == 'X'`, ... Y están todas toditas [perfectamente documentadas](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar el operador [].

Lo podes hacer asi:

```cpp
if (aux[0][0] == 'c'){
    cout << "correcto";
    }
}
```

[Te dejo el link a la documentación](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)

Comment: Esta respuesta utiliza practicante notación de arreglos. No es lo más aconsejable. Aquí aux parece todo menos una variable string. Podrías haber utilizado  aux[0].compare(0,1,"c")

Answer (score 2):

> ese método solo está disponible a partir de la versión 11 de C++

Esto es *casi* correcto, no es la versión 11 si no la versión que fue publicada en 2011. El resto de lo que publicas es incorrecto, veamos por qué:

- `string::front` devuelve un carácter y lo comparas con un puntero.

  ```
  if (aux[0].front() == "c"){
    cout << "correcto";
  }
  ```

  En [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) los literales de cadena (el texto que se pone entre comillas dobles) es una formación<sup>1</sup> de caracteres, en concreto el literal `"c"` es una formación de dos caracteres siendo el primero `'c'` y el segundo `'\0'`, cuando comparas el carácter devuelto por `string::front` con `"c"` en realidad estás comparando un carácter contra el puntero que forma la formación; seguramente querías hacer esto:

  ```
  if (aux[0].front() == 'c'){
  //                    ^ ^ <--- Comillas simples, comparas carácter contra carácter.
    cout << "correcto";
  }
  ```
- No deberías usar cabeceras de [c](/questions/tagged/c) si estás programando en C++. Las cabeceras  `<stdlib.h>`, `<conio.h>` y `<string.h>` pertenecen a C, dispones de versiones adaptadas a C++ cuyo nombre es el mismo eliminando la extensión y añadiendo el prefijo `c`: `<cstdlib>`, `<cstring>`. En cuanto a `<conio.h>` no forma parte de C estándar y no ha sido adaptada a C++.
- Duplicas funcionalidades. La cabecera `<iostream>` y la cabecera `<cstdio>` ofrecen herramientas para interactuar con la consola, la primera es puramente C++ y la segunda una adaptación a C++ de una cabecera C. Dado que programas en C++ no tienes que usar la segunda.
- La cabecera que contiene el objeto `std::string` es `<string>` y es la que debes usar en lugar de `<string.h>` que no contiene dicho objeto.

Aclarados esos puntos, vamos a la pregunta:

> ¿Qué alternativas existen al método `string::front`?

- El contenido del iterador inicial:

  ```
  if (*aux[0].begin() == 'c'){
      std::cout << "correcto";
  }
  ```
- El contenido del primer elemento:

  ```
  if (aux[0][0] == 'c'){
      std::cout << "correcto";
  }
  ```
- El contenido del primer elemento de la versión puntero de la cadena:

  ```
  if (*aux[0].c_str() == 'c'){
      std::cout << "correcto";
  }
  ```
- La función miembro `string::compare`

  ```
  if (aux[0].compare(0, 1, "c") == 0){
      std::cout << "correcto";
  }
  ```
- La función miembro `string::at`:

  ```
  if (*aux[0].at(0) == 'c'){
      std::cout << "correcto";
  }
  ```
- La función miembro `string::find_first_of`:

  ```
  if (aux[0].find_first_of("c", 0) == 0){
      std::cout << "correcto";
  }
  ```

---

<sup>1</sup>También conocida como *arreglo* o en inglés *array*.